# Replace Numbers within a column in R

Tags: r, replace

I have dfs with df$col and I want to replace all 1 between a higher number with the higher number itself, like 2111112 turns to 2222222, and 311113 to 333333 and so on and keep the overall pattern as well with 0 etc. so just replace 1 into the higher number on the exact place. One example:

```
data <- data.frame(col = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0)))

desired.outut.data <- data.frame(col = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0)))
```

The amount of 1 between higher numbers can change in different dfs.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you please edit your question to include your desired output, and it would likely be helpful to parse down your current same data to a *minimal* reproducible example of just a few rows. Good luck!

Comment: What should happen if there's ever a situation like 54111145?

Comment: there is no situation like that - always 000 -higher number-11111- higher number - 0000

Comment: Are the groups always separated by zero(es)?

Comment: Yes, the groups are always separated by zeros

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a more elegant way:

```
library(dplyr)
data |>
  mutate(grp = cumsum(col != lag(col, 1, 0))) |>
  mutate(new_val = if_else(col == 0, 0, 
                           slider::slide_index_dbl(
                             col, grp, max, .before = 1)))
```

Result

```
   col grp new_val
1    0   0       0
2    0   0       0
3    0   0       0
4    0   0       0
5    1   1       1
6    1   1       1
7    1   1       1
8    1   1       1
9    0   2       0
10   0   2       0
11   0   2       0
12   0   2       0
13   2   3       2
14   1   4       2
15   1   4       2
16   1   4       2
17   1   4       2
18   2   5       2
19   0   6       0
20   0   6       0
21   0   6       0
22   0   6       0
23   3   7       3
24   1   8       3
25   1   8       3
26   3   9       3
27   0  10       0
28   0  10       0
29   0  10       0
30   0  10       0
31   4  11       4
32   1  12       4
33   1  12       4
34   1  12       4
35   1  12       4
36   4  13       4
37   0  14       0
38   0  14       0
39   0  14       0
40   5  15       5
41   1  16       5
42   1  16       5
43   1  16       5
44   1  16       5
45   1  16       5
46   5  17       5
47   0  18       0
48   0  18       0
49   0  18       0
```

Comment: I get an error message: Error in `mutate()`:
i In argument: `grp = cumsum(col != lag(col, default = first(col)))`.
Caused by error in `lag()`:
! `x` must be a vector, not a function.

Comment: I think the `default` parameter requires a constant (0 in my suggestion), not a calculation (`first(col)` in your version).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach with `fill`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
  mutate(col = na_if(col, 1),
         col = ifelse(is.na(col) & row_number() < 10, 1, col)) %>% 
  fill(col, .direction = "down")%>% 
  pull()
```

```
[1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 4 4 4 4 4 4 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can split by indices that we create for values `x != 0` and use the `max` for the positions, using `ave`.

```
> transform(data, col=ave(x, replace(cumsum(c(0, diff(x != 0)) == 1), x == 0, 0), FUN=max))
   col
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    1
6    1
7    1
8    1
9    0
10   0
11   0
12   0
13   2
14   2
15   2
16   2
17   2
18   2
19   0
20   0
21   0
22   0
23   3
24   3
25   3
26   3
27   0
28   0
29   0
30   0
31   4
32   4
33   4
34   4
35   4
36   4
37   0
38   0
39   0
40   5
41   5
42   5
43   5
44   5
45   5
46   5
47   0
48   0
49   0
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(col = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-49L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Analogous to jay.sf's approach, but translated to tidy and maybe a little bit easier to read

```r
library(tidyverse)
data <- data.frame(col = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0))

mod <- data %>% 
  mutate(
    # create variable for grouping, splitting in 0 and non-zero blocks
    non_zero = (col != 0) %>% replace_na(FALSE),
    group    = consecutive_id(non_zero)
  ) %>% 
  # per group, replace all values by their respective maximum
  mutate(
    .by    = group,
    result = max(col),
    .after = col
  )

library(waldo)
desired.output <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0)
waldo::compare(mod$result, desired.output)
#> ✔ No differences
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>